# Simple Web3 installation

Tags: javascript, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I have been trying to inject metamask into my site using web3. I have called web3 in my site as below and started the site using local server(VS Code extension which gives me port:5500)

```
    window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
      if (window.ethereum) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
        try {
          await ethereum.enable();
          initPayButton()
        } catch (err) {
          $('#status').html('User denied account access', err)
        }
      } else if (window.web3) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider)
        initPayButton()
      } else {
        $('#status').html('No Metamask (or other Web3 Provider) installed')
      }
    })
```

Later I am calling my contracts as below and I am facing troubles.

pay() is a function that happens with a button click in my HTML. It needs payout() function to be called from my Smart contract so initially I defined it as you can see below in 1st line.

```
    window.contract = new window.web3.eth.Contract(
           [  abi    ] , '0xC4AfE8504a711bE2D5E25b45eb72fC3f0924aB21');
        
        
        
        function pay() {

            var paymentAddress = document.getElementById("address").value;
            var val = document.getElementById("weight").value;
            var type= document.getElementById("category").value;

               
            contract.methods.payout.sendTransaction( paymentAddress ,val,type )
            //updateStatus('Updated.');
        }
```

I am getting the following error

```
MetaMask no longer injects web3

Uncaught TypeError: window.web3.eth is undefined
```

I have tried lot of ways but couldn't go further please help me.

Comment: What is the goal you're trying to achieve? To have the user call the contract `payout()` function by sending a transaction from their Metamask?